# Speed Increases with Every New instance of Object

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm having an issue in my game where the more objects that spawn, the faster these instances of the objects go. They almost double their speed every time a new one spawns.

This is what is currently used to move the objects:

```
public void goRight(){
    this.setX((this.getX()+this.getSpeed()));
    this.isMoving=true;
    this.stopMovingLeft();
    this.stopMovingUp();
    this.stopMovingDown();
    this.stopMovingUpRight();
    this.stopMovingUpLeft();
    this.stopMovingDownLeft();
    this.stopMovingDownRight();
    this.isMovingRight=true;
}

public void goLeft(){
    this.setX((this.getX()-this.getSpeed()));
    this.isMoving=true; 
    this.stopMovingRight(); 
    this.stopMovingUp(); 
    this.stopMovingDown(); 
    this.stopMovingUpRight(); 
    this.stopMovingUpLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingDownLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingDownRight(); 
    this.isMovingLeft=true;
}

public void goUp(){
    this.setY((this.getY()-this.getSpeed())); 
    this.isMoving=true; 
    this.stopMovingLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingRight(); 
    this.stopMovingDown(); 
    this.stopMovingUpRight(); 
    this.stopMovingUpLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingDownLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingDownRight(); 
    this.isMovingUp=true;
}

public void goDown(){
    this.setY((this.getY()+this.getSpeed())); 
    this.isMoving=true; 
    this.stopMovingLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingRight(); 
    this.stopMovingUp(); 
    this.stopMovingUpRight(); 
    this.stopMovingUpLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingDownLeft(); 
    this.stopMovingDownRight(); 
    this.isMovingDown=true;
}


public BetaMonster(){
    this.hp=10;
    this.frame=0;
    this.attack=1;
    this.setSpeed(2f);
    this.setSprite("res/Images/Sprites/Monster/MonsterSheet.png");
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException {  

    if(levelMusic.playing()!=true){levelMusic.loop();}
    centerCharX=camX+screenWideOffset-(pocky.getSprite(0, 0).getScaledCopy(3f).getWidth()/2);//Find Center of Character 1
    centerCharY=camY+screenHighOffset-(pocky.getSprite(0, 0).getScaledCopy(3f).getHeight()/2);//Find Center of Character 1
    timer+=delta;//Timer
    controller.poll();//Poll Controller Buttons

    for(int f=0; f<spawnList.size(); f++){
            final Iterator<SpawnPoint> spawnIter = spawnList.iterator();
            while(spawnIter.hasNext()){
            final SpawnPoint spawn = spawnIter.next();
            if((timer/1000)>spawnCount){
            spawnCount+=5;
            BetaMonster ghost = new BetaMonster();
            ghost.setAtk(0);
            ghost.setCollidable(true);
            ghost.setHP(5);
            ghost.setX(spawn.getSpawnX());
            ghost.setY(spawn.getSpawnY());
            ghost.setWidth(32);
                ghost.setHeight(32);
            ghostList.add(ghost);
            }
        }
    }
    controlFlags(gc);//Check Keys and Flag Use
    scrollCam(gc);//Camera Movement Check from Control
    moveChar(gc);//Character Movement
    checkPlayerMoving();//Check Player's Movement with Animations
    projectilePhysics();//Checks Projectile Physics
    if(collideThread.isAlive()==false){collideThread.run();}//Ensure Thread is Running
    collideThread.checkCollision(timer, playerProjectiles, player, tileList); //Check Projectiles against their time to Die. Must rename when can be arsed.
    collideThread.playerTileCollission(playerProjectiles, player, tileList);//Checks player-tile collision
    collideThread.checkTileProjectileCollision(playerProjectiles, player, tileList);//Checks projectile-tile collision
    collideThread.checkMonsterProjectileCollision(playerProjectiles, player, ghostList);//Checks monster-projectile collision
    for(int k = 0; k<ghostList.size(); k++){
        BetaMonster monsters = ghostList.get(k);
        Rectangle tempRect = new Rectangle(player.getX()-490, player.getY()-200, 64, 64);
        collideThread.monsterLogic(player, ghostList);
        if(monsters.getBoundingBox().intersects(tempRect)==true){}//TODO If Player and Monster Intersect, Do Damage.    
        if(monsters.getBoundingBox().intersects(tempRect)==true && defendKey==true){monsters.takeDamage(player.getDamage()*3);}
    }//End For Loop
}//end Update
```

Apologies if my post needs more info, I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: Post the constructor if this happens every time a new object is created. On a side note, you should factor out all the stop... methods to a helper function to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Please post the rest of the class.

Comment: I added the constructor under the previous code.

Comment: Please also post your update method

Comment: I added the update method, but the editor seems to be acting screwy.

Comment: Maybe your speed variable is static? Or your `setSpeed()` function is screwy?

Comment: it is not static.

public void setSpeed(float newSpeed){this.speed = newSpeed;}public float getSpeed(){return this.speed;}

Comment: What about the fps? Does that change?

Comment: No, it stays locked at ~60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It had to do with calling the ghost.update(); method in the iterator rather than as a part of the linkedlist.

```
for(int k = 0; k<clickList.size(); k++){
clickList.get(k).update();}
```